# How to optimize an algorithm for matching multipart rar files from input in php

Tags: php, algorithm, arrays, archive, multipart

I'm looking for a better optimized way to find and group multipart archives from an array of filenames

I have as an input for example:

```
array(
books.part1.rar,
books.part3.rar,
00000114.rar,
svoy_20ostrov.rar,
svoy_20ostrov.rar,
koncert_20v_20dk_20mir.rar,
koncert_20v_20centralnom_20teatre_20kukol.rar,
LP_LIVE_PR_Tampa.part2.rar,
koncert_20v_20dk_20vami.rar,
koncert_20v_20dk_20kommuna_20chast1.rar,
books.part2.rar,
koncert_20v_20dk_20kommuna_20chast2.rar,
books.part4.rar,
recedivist.rar,
LP_LIVE_PR_Tampa.part1.rar
)
```

And I'm looking for the output

```
array(  

array(

books.part1.rar
books.part2.rar
books.part3.rar
books.part4.rar ) ,

00000114.rar
svoy_20ostrov.rar
koncert_20v_20dk_20mir.rar
koncert_20v_20centralnom_20teatre_20kukol.rar
koncert_20v_20dk_20vami.rar

array(
koncert_20v_20dk_20kommuna_20chast1.rar
koncert_20v_20dk_20kommuna_20chast2.rar
)

recedivist.rar
array (
LP_LIVE_PR_Tampa.part1.rar
LP_LIVE_PR_Tampa.part2.rar
)
)
```

I'm using php as a programming language, by the way,

An idea was to match with a regular expression files like (.+).part1.rar then when found , match all the other part([0-9]+).rar (other foreach required that loops through all array) and when found unset() those entries and add them to the new constructed array

Comment: How does `00000114.rar` relate to `svoy_20ostrov.rar`? Or `recedivist.rar` to `LP_LIVE_PR_Tampa.part1.rar`? Some of the groupings make sense, but some don't.

Comment: just the partXX.rar will be grouped, the rest won't relate, so they will remain ungrouped

Comment: thank you for you suggestion, i just accepted valid answers for my questions. some are  still unanswered though, wierd..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would sort the array first and then loop through it, performing the Levenshtein() function on the next entry.

```
$rars = array(
    books.part1.rar,
    books.part3.rar,
    00000114.rar,
    svoy_20ostrov.rar,
    svoy_20ostrov.rar,
    koncert_20v_20dk_20mir.rar,
    koncert_20v_20centralnom_20teatre_20kukol.rar,
    LP_LIVE_PR_Tampa.part2.rar,
    koncert_20v_20dk_20vami.rar,
    koncert_20v_20dk_20kommuna_20chast1.rar,
    books.part2.rar,
    koncert_20v_20dk_20kommuna_20chast2.rar,
    books.part4.rar,
    recedivist.rar,
    LP_LIVE_PR_Tampa.part1.rar
)

sort($rars);
$current = 0;
$rars_complete = array();
foreach($rars as $i=>$rar) {
    $next = ($i + 1) < count($rars)) ? $i + 1 : false;
    $rars_complete[$current][] = $rar;
    if($next != false && levenshtein($rar, $rars[$next]) == 1)
        continue;
    else
        $current++;
}
```

Note, this is not tested.

Comment: wow, i didn't knew about this function :) yes this solves a lot of problems

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just sort the array? Then all you have to do is detect when the begin of the string changes to see when a new set started.

Comment: yes, i can make a custom usort  with a callback function. Good ideea thank you :)